# How to solve -------undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'-------on mingw

Tags: c++, linker, g++, mingw

I have just install gcc and g++ on mingw.
I wrote a very simple "hello world" program to test if the g++ compiler worked.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "hello world" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ Test.cpp
```

And then some errors appear:

```
D:/MinGW[Finished in 0.6s with exit code    1]/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../mingw32/lib/crt2.o: In function `_mingw_setargv':
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o): In function `glob_match':
i:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.0-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/misc/glob.c:733: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o): In function `glob_strdup':
i:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.0-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/misc/glob.c:85: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o): In function `glob_match':
i:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.0-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/misc/glob.c:841: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o): In function `glob_strdup':
i:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.0-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/misc/glob.c:85: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):i:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.0-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/misc/glob.c:85: more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Looks like a version conflict `mingw32/3.4.5/` and `mingwrt-4.0-1`. It looks like your linking to old libs `3.4.5`.

Comment: but I have upgraded mingw with MinGW Installation Manager.How can I know the version of mingwrt? Thank you!

Comment: Just as you said, I found that is a version conflict.
When I checked the package I have installed, I found I carelessly add the old version(2006 version) of gcc and g++. Then I uninstall them and install the current version of gcc and g++, my problem is solved.Thanks again.

Comment: Great idea guys. Talking away among yourselves on SO isn't going to bring this to the attention of anyone who might be in a position to actually _do_ something about the issue; you need to raise it through the processes documented on http://mingw.org

Comment: we're using gcc 7.4 and just ran into this error....

Comment: In case any future Googlers are in my boat, I had a hard requirement on the `-fshort-double` option, which was last present and working in GCC 4.5.2. It seemed that w32api 3.15-1 and mingwrt 3.18 were the magic versions which worked correctly with that GCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orig problem seems solved regarding linking against old libs, but I have opposite case.
I need to work with older GCC 3.4 version, so I installed gcc-v3-core package.
Then orig errors immediately appear when linking a trivial source.
I found out that MinGW GCC 3.4 cannot work with mingwrt > 3.20 and the problem is that gcc-v3-core contains incorrect mingwrt spec, allowing newest vesions.

The solution is simple:

```
mingw-get upgrade "mingwrt=3.20.*"
```

!Update!
Actually with mingwrt-3.20 linker reports same errors for C++ code:

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

BAM!

Solution 2:

```
mingw-get upgrade "mingwrt=3.18.*"
```

the last one that seems to work with gcc-v3-g++.

Comment: BTW: all info regarding MinGW GCC 3.4 installation is outdated/incomplete. I had to experiment with packages myself. One very important thing is: gcc-v3 needs libgcc which isn't provided at MinGW/Base/gcc/Version3 nor in gcc-v3. Had to get it from Version4.

Comment: If you are using a libgcc from GCC-4.x along with a GCC-3.x compiler, then you are headed for some big trouble -- the two are _not_ intended to work together, and are fundamentally incompatible. GCC-3.x does _not_ need any GCC libraries which are not provided with it. That you are seeing this dependency suggests that you are mixing _other_ libraries, which have been compiled with GCC-4.x, into your GCC-3.x tool chain; you need to recompile those libraries with GCC-3.x.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but this is _not_ a solution! If you _must_ use an ancient, obsolete, and long unsupported version of GCC (why?), then the solution is to ensure that _every_ library you use along with it has been compiled with that self-same obsolete version of GCC. Naturally, this becomes increasingly difficult to ensure, unless _you_ invest the effort to build every one of those libraries yourself, from source.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an authoritative answer, from a MinGW project administrator.

Your problem arises because you continue to use an obsolete, (no longer maintained; no longer supported), version of GCC. Current versions of `mingwrt` are compiled using GCC-4.x, (I used GCC-4.8.2 for `mingwrt-3.21` and its descendants), and this introduces the dependencies on `__chkstk_ms`, (which is provided by `libgcc` -- a GCC-4.x specific library, which is incompatible with GCC-3.x).

FWIW, I can reproduce your issue if I install a GCC-4.8.2 built `mingwrt-3.21.1` into a GCC-3.4.5 installation. By the same token, I can also successfully use `mingwrt-3.21.1` with GCC-3.4.5, *if I build it with that same version of GCC*.

Thus, for an authoritative answer: if you *must* continue to use an obsolete GCC version, *you* need to be prepared to rebuild *all* associated libraries, using that same obsolete compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a "modern" answer to the original question: You may miss the stdc++ and gcc library in MinGW, have to link them by yourself manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which arose because I foolishly installed a newer version into an old installation.  The fix was obvious, I backed up my old installation, then deleted it and done a fresh install.  Everything compiled perfectly.  Old habits die hard I guess. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Simply install and run the GCC in Windows XP.

I tested exactly the same MinGW binaries (based on GCC-3.4.5) in Windows_10_x64_b1607 and Windows_XP_SP3.
Windows 10 generates `__chkstk_ms` errors, but in Windows XP everything is fine.

Answer (score -5):

- To compile a .cpp file you have to issue the following command for it to compile. I suggest you use  gcc instead of g++, they both work either way.
- gcc -c Test.cpp -o Test.exe
- Or with g++
- g++ -c Test.cpp -o Test.exe

Comment: -1: `gcc --help` says: `-c Compile and assemble, but do not link`. And `-o <file> Place the output into <file>`. So your "solution" consist to build an object file without linking and rename it!

Comment: @Aerospace, in fact this so called solution is just plain no such thing -- it is entirely misguided, and utterly _wrong_! Separate compilation and linking by all means, using `g++ -c test.cpp`, followed by `g++ -o test.exe test.o`. Furthermore, while one may get away with using `gcc -c test.cpp` in the first step, it _isn't_ recommended; for the second step, it is entirely unsuitable.