# mingw building error: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw

I've just installed mingw in windows, and I write a helloWorld program to test it. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
C:/MinGW/lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):glob.c:(.text+0x5e3): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):glob.c:(.text+0x690): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):glob.c:(.text+0x7e9): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):glob.c:(.text+0x82d): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):glob.c:(.text+0xc0d): more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
```

There is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw). But I checked the MinGW installation manager and it seems taht I didn't install old version of gcc or g++. Can any buddy help? Thanks!

By the way, since I'm using pythonxy as my python environment, there is also a C:/MinGW32-xy directory under my C:, which is not included in the system variable 'path'. Would that affect?

Comment: Try deleting C:\Mingw folder re-run the Installation manager

Comment: how did you compile it?

Comment: I'm trying to build it in the sublime text3. However, I also used cmd line: "gcc -o filename.exe filename.c" and still got the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve -------undefined reference to \`\_\_chkstk\_ms'-------on mingw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I checked my system varialble in detail and found that the C:/MinGW32-xy/bin was before C:/MinGW/bin. So when I typed gcc -v in the command line, it shows that MinGW32-xy was at work. I switched their order, the problem was solved.
However, I don't really know the difference between the MinGW and MinGW32-xy. Can any buddy give me a hint?

Comment: Did you previously install another version of mingw? It may have been included with an IDE you downloaded perhaps? It's best not to mix multiple mingw installs on your machine unless you have some special requirements and know exactly how to deal with it.

Comment: That is my problem. As I said, I installed pythonxy before and it installed a MinGW and a MinGW32-xy for me, which cause the problem. I installed pythonxy because that helped me solve a version conflict issue.

Answer (score 0):

i use mingw 4.7.1

i make a file name main.cpp in E:\Portable Apps

my gcc is in C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin

i type this in cmd (cmd = command line) and it work fine for me:

```
e:
cd\Portable Apps
"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc" -c "main.cpp"
"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc" "main.o" -o "hello 1.exe" -L"main.cpp"
```