# I'm having a problem with the g++ compiler on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I was building a very very basic program in Visual Studio Code using C++ and g++ as my compiler. And I got a lot of errors:

```
g++ main.cpp

main.cpp:16:2: warning: no newline at end of file
/mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(setargv.o):(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x6d2): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x8b8): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x900): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xa25): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xc15): more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status'
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve -------undefined reference to \`\_\_chkstk\_ms'-------on mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw) or [mingw building error: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135923/mingw-building-error-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms)

Comment: **"using C++ and g++ as my compiler"** If you want to mix objects built with two different compilers? If so, I would suggest you rethink this approach and use either Visual C++ for the entire project or MinGW for the entire project. One of the general guidelines of building is, don't mix objects built from different compilers, or even different versions of the same compiler. Two compilers may not do things in the same way and this can lead to data corruption and outright application crashes.

Comment: I re-install mingw-w64 and I got the same error.

Comment: I did mingw-get upgrade "mingwrt=3.20.*" but what version should I be upgrading to?

Comment: Actually with mingwrt-3.20 linker reports same errors. I suggest you could refer to the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw