# mingw gcc not working g++ does

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I had been previously using g++ on code i was compiling and it was, and still does work great.

Now i need to use C instead of C++ and have been attempting us gcc.

I get this error:

```
gcc codemon.c -Wall -o codemon.exe
/mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(setargv.o):(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x673): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x7e0): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x81d): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x934): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xb78): more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib
/libmingwex.a(glob.o): bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: final link
 failed: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 1
```

I'm using windows 8.1.

if i use g++ for the same program it works fine.

from similar questions i have gathered that this is probably an error where my C librarys and my compiler are different versions, but i have tried updating mingw and had zero success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve -------undefined reference to \`\_\_chkstk\_ms'-------on mingw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw). Make sure your MinGW installation is updated to the latest versions (do a complete reinstall if necessary).