# MinGW gcc, undefined reference to __chstk_ms?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

So I've just got a brand new laptop (Windows 10) and have been installing everything I need.

I downloaded MinGW and installed gcc, added it the PATH etc. I thought I would compile a completely standard, basic HelloWorld C program just to check that it works. (This file has been copied straight across from my old laptop where it compiles perfectly). This is what I got:

```
C:\...\Documents\C>gcc prog1.c -o prog1
/mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(setargv.o):(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x673): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x7e0): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x81d): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x934): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
/mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xb78): more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Previous questions similar to this have been the result of version conflicts, which, as far as I can tell, I don't have. And since the laptop is brand new I don't have any previously installed things that I've forgotten about which could be conflicting.

Any help on fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw

Comment: As I said, previous questions suggest version conflicts, which as far as I tell I do not have.

Comment: And where you link the standard library which contains `__chkstk_ms`?