# code:blocks debugging problem in c++ for first start

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm just starting to use code blocks for developing c++ but unfortunately I have problem in debugging my first code.

the code is here :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but after debugging it has the log is here :

C:\Ming W\bin..\lib\GCC\mingw 32\3.4.5......\libmingwex.a(glob.o)|| undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'|

the compiler setting  is here :

[image]

the debugger setting is here :

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve -------undefined reference to \`\_\_chkstk\_ms'-------on mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw)

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't know any thing about the version of mingw and g++, I think the problem is remain! please help me step by step if you know how to solve it!!