# Newly downloaded gcc throws undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' error

Tags: c, gcc, g++, mingw

I recently downloaded gcc and g++ compiler using MinGW and tried a simple hello world printing file in c. Whenever I run the code using visual studio code(using the code-runner extension made by jun han), I run into the following error:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingw32.a(setargv.o):(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x6d2): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'  
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x8b8): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x900): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xa25): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xc15): more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**NOTE: I HAVE SEEN [THE POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw) BY [YUNUS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747023/yunus)**

Comment: Don't write in ALL CAPS, it's considered rude. You've already used bold which is more than enough

Comment: The post you have seen seems to be right, where did you download your g++ compiler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.4.5, is that the version? That's very old!

Which MinGW were you using exactly?

I recommend using MinGW-w64 as it's more up to date.

You can get a standalone build from https://winlibs.com/

As for your errors, they are related to stack protection settings. Make sure you don't have different MinGW's in your system or referred to by environment variables like `PATH`.

Comment: I am gotta try it right now!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can now learn to use C and C++ finally!

Answer (score 0):

add gcc path to you envionment variables

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).