# MingGw error while trying to complie C code

Tags: c, mingw

I tried to compile my C code (using mingw) into a EXE file but it just says the following error:

`` /mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(setargv.o):(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x6d2): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x8b8): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x900): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xa25): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xc15): more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow collect2: ld returned 1 exit status ``

i ran the command

> mingw-get upgrade "mingwer=3.20.*"

and

> mingw-get upgrade "mingwer=3.18.*"

but didn't solve the issue

**Edit:** Command ran

> gcc compvisia.c init.c bitboards.c hashkeys.c board.c -o compvisia

Code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() {
   printf("hello world");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And yes i ran gcc instead of g++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve -------undefined reference to \`\_\_chkstk\_ms'-------on mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw)

Comment: @stark I've seen that post and did what the answer said but it didn't fix it.

Comment: What version of gcc do you have?

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the command you show us? -- Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] together with the requested version information.

Comment: @stark i've got gcc version 3.4.5 and g++ version 6.3.0

Comment: gcc version 4 was released in 2005 and is no longer supported.  The current version of gcc is 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the errors are related to stack protection.

Maybe your system has a mix of different MinGW versions installed, causing linking with mismatching libraries.

MinGW 3 is old, you should really consider moving to MinGW-w64.

You can get a standalone build of MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ that you can extract somewhere without installing to test if it makes a difference for your source code.

Make sure to use the full path to `gcc.exe` so you are in fact using the one you think you are using.

Comment: I've installed MinGW-w64 but it didn't make a difference

Comment: We're still not seeing minimal reproducible code in your question... Which code and which build commands do you trigger this error with?

Comment: I"ve added the code i want to run. (yes it says other files but they are just empty) (and yes ive tried removing that from the command but it changed nothing)

Comment: Which `gcc` were you using? Please try using the full path to `gcc.exe` to be sure it's running the one you think it is...

Comment: I'm still using gcc 3.4.5. But i have updated it so idk what went wrong.

Comment: Don't! That's really old. Latest GCC is version 11! Also you seem to be mixing different versions of `gcc` and `g++` which is a really bad idea. Switch from MinGW to MinGW-w64, and if you still use the old MSYS, switch to MSYS2.