# Dev c++ [Linker error] undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'

Tags: mingw, linker-errors, dev-c++

I installed dev c++ for the first time on my laptop. I had done all the following steps below: Tools > Compiler Option > Directories > Binaries, C Include, C+ include, Libraries

I deleted all the default paths and replaced them to C:/MinGW. The MinGW works on visual studio but not on Dev C++.

I named the file Untitled1.c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    printf("hello");
    
    }



    [Linker error] undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
    [Linker error] undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'  
    [Linker error] undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' 
    [Linker error] undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' 
    [Linker error] undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' 
    more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve -------undefined reference to \`\_\_chkstk\_ms'-------on mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw)